# Will bounty be given to the accepted answer?

Tags: support, bounty, voting, accepted-answer

There is a question which had a bounty and it was given to the highest voted answer (as the faq says), but **none** of the answers has been accepted yet.

What if someone answers this question (perhaps after a long time), and the new answer gets more votes than the answer that was originally awarded the bounty? Suppose the OP even unaccepts the originally accepted answer and accepts this new answer.

In this situation, will the bounty be given to the new answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once a bounty is awarded (or the bounty period has expired if the bounty has not been awarded), you can't remove the bounty from one answer and award it to another.

What you *can* do, is to start another bounty and award it to the new answer as you see it fits.